# Why does Padmé have so many outfits?

Tags: star-wars, padme

In the *Star Wars* prequels, Padmé Amidala wears an insane amount of regal and ornate outfits. In *The Phantom Menace* alone, she wears at a minimum nine different outfits. For comparison, (if memory serves) Princess Leia wears eight outfits in the entire original trilogy. I have read the canon book *Queen's Shadow*, which explains the in-universe reason for her having so many clothes, but what was the out of universe reason for making her wear all those clothes?

Comment: To sell toys to little girls.

Comment: Queen Amidala is a politician and diplomat. In real life, people like that use(d) their clothes to send subtle signals. Going on a delicate state visit? Wearing something in your host's national colors might win you some hearts. You want to reprimand somebody without saying it out loud? For the next visit, wear something you've worn before, signaling "You're not important enough for a new dress". People tried to "read" from Queen Elizabeth's clothing what she thought about her grandson's spouse. To send signals like that, you need an extensive wardrobe.

Comment: @Valorum doubtless the real reason was to sell action figures, but *were* dolls of Amidala ever popular with little girls? (genuine question, btw)

Comment: @AndresF. - They were hugely popular at the time. They sold like hot cakes and were frequently sold out in stores; https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=S4gPVjV6l9A

Comment: Mrs. Howell Syndrome?

Comment: @HenningKockerbeck: Another example: The Queen prominently wore a broche gifted to her by Michelle Obama when she greeted Donald Trump.

Comment: Extremely simple, she is a Head of State, a Princess.

Comment: In a documentary about _Dowton Abbey,_ they claimed aristocratic women sometimes wore four or more different outfits a day. Even with ladies' maids helping them, they spent a considerable part of their days getting dressed and undressed. It's what you do when you're part of the 0.001%

Comment: @MikeHarris That is the real reason Padme had a body double and walked around in a guard outfit herself. Who wants to live like that?

Comment: @MikeHarris - It keeps the staff busy and out of trouble.

Comment: I think the bigger question is why you have so few outfits?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

This is discussed in the *Star Wars Episode I: [DVD Costumes Featurette](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6cWexTfyzUI)*. In short, Padmé's outfits create a feeling of grandeur, sophistication and elegance (as befits someone of her noble station) and are intended to 'wow' the audience.

> **Trisha Biggar (Costume Designer):** *When I first started in the film, we were going to have three costumes for the queen. And, as time went on George decided that every time we saw the queen, that she was going to have a different costume.*
>
> **George Lucas (Writer/Director):** *Somebody of that stature would automatically be changing her costumes to fit the occasion. She travels, she goes to the senate, she has all these official functions and non-official functions, and each one of those demands a different type of costume.*
> ...
> *In the other films I've been involved with, it's always been a very simple wardrobe. This became a very complex, very designed, very fashionable wardrobe.*
>
> **Rick McCallum (Producer):** *I think people will be amazed by the costumes. The images are so haunting and so beautiful and I think it's something that they've never seen or witnessed before in any previous Star Wars film*

Comment: Could have been said in a lot fewer words.  "She's a princess."  But I still like the answer. 

Answer (score 0):

She had a lot less outfits than Princess Diana or Jackie Kennedy for example.  People in such positions are often expected to never be seen in the same outfit twice.

Comment: 9 outfits are not exactly a lot, especially if you count both casual and formal wear. Have you ever raised a teenager? Only in comic books and SF/fantasy movies do people wear the same outfit all the time.